# Is it possible to find a (nonsquare) integer which is a quadratic residues modulo a given infinite list of primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I'm wondering if it's possible, given a prime p and an infinite list of primes $q_1$, $q_2$, ... to find an integer d which (1) is *not* a square mod p, but (2) *is* a square mod $q_i$ for all i.  Always, sometimes, never?  Probably sometimes --- what are some conditions?  In the application I have in mind, the $q_i$ are all the prime divisors of the numbers $p^{2^n}-1$ as n ranges from 1 to infinity, but that's somewhat flexible.

(The application, by the way, involves taking a p-adic interpolation of exponentiation of rational integers, and extending it to rings of integers in towers of number fields.)

[ETA:  I forgot to mention that d should also be a square mod 8 for the application, which rules out the answer of -1 given below.]

- For a finite list, d can be constructed using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but that doesn't seem to help here.
- Given d, quadratic reciprocity gives an infinite set of primes for which d is a square, but I need the primes specified first.
- Grunwald-Wang says, if I understand it correctly, that condition (1) implies that d is *not* a square modulo $q$ for infinitely many primes $q$, but doesn't say anything about primes which d *is* a square for.
- The Chebotarov Density Theorem seems to imply that the set of possible d has density zero, but doesn't rule out (or imply) that one such d exists.

Thanks for any help, sources, or advice!

----Josh

Comment: Well, if $q$ were the set of all primes (Except p) or even just density more than half, then we know that $d$ is a square in the rationals. So we should assume the $q$ are sparse enough.

Comment: In the other direction, if the sequence $q_i$ is such that for every (squarefree?) $d$, the $q_i$ fill up more than half the residue classes modulo $d$, then again the condition can't be satisfied. Both these observations follow from the fact that for fixed $d$, exactly half the primes (and half the residue classes modulo $d$) split in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt(d))$.

Comment: Note that we can find a sequence of primes $q_i$ that fill up residue classes modulo $d$ for every $d$ but are very sparse among all primes: We just enumerate through each d and each residue class modulo $d$ and the choose the next prime to be in this residue class but very large otherwise. So these two conditions are really independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the given list of primes. A simpler but necessary condition is that there be a $d$ so that all the primes of the list (greater than $d$) are concentrated in a few congruence classes $\bmod 4d.$ We can stick to odd prime divisors since everything is a quadratic residue $\bmod 2.$

If the list is all primes congruent to $1 \bmod 4$ then $-1$ is a common quadratic residue. That probably doesn't seem very exciting.

If the list is all odd prime divisors of $3^{2^n}-1$ as $n$ ranges over the positive integers then $-1$ is again a common quadratic residue. That is the kind of thing you were mentioning. But the reason is that all those primes are $1 \bmod 4$

If I am not mistaken, and for the same reason, $-1$ is a common quadratic residue of of the prime divisors of $p^{2^n}-1$ as $n$ ranges over the integers starting at $2.$

For certain primes , such as $5,7,17,19,31,53,59$ we can expand the list to all prime divisors of $p^{2^n}-1$ with the exception of $3.$ In general it is sufficient to discard any divisors of $p^2-1$ which are $3 \bmod 4.$

The facts behind this are

- $p^{2^n}-1=(p-1)(p+1)(p^2+1)(p^4+1)\cdots(p^{2^{n-1}}+1)$
- every odd factor of $p^{2^m}+1$ is of the form  $2^{m+1}q+1$
- $-1$ is a quadratic residue for primes which are $1 \bmod 4.$

---

Think first about this (easy) question. For fixed $d$ what are the odd primes $q$ such that $d$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod q?$ Call this set $G_d.$ We may assume that $d$ is squarefree.

Then the members of $G_d$ are the prime divisors of $d$ along with those primes in a union of certain congruence classes $\bmod 4d.$ Half of the classes $(r \bmod 4d)$ with $\gcd(r,4d)=1$

In some cases ($d$ even or $d$ odd with all divisors $1 \bmod 4$) it suffices to consider congruence classes $\bmod 2d$. However what is written is still correct. I  will ignore your $p$ on the assumption that the goal was to rule out $d$ being a square.

Then the specific $d$ works for a particular instance of your problem, precisely if the chosen list is one of the uncountably many infinite subsets of $G_d.$

On the other hand, suppose it is given that the members of the list (other than the divisors of $d$ in the list, if any) are chosen from some $k \ll \phi(d)$ of the congruence classes $\bmod 4d$. Then, if the $k$ are chosen at random, the chance that $d$ will work is less than $2^{-k}$.

So starting from a list $\mathbf{q}=q_1,q_2,\cdots$ the first question is "Is there some reason to suspect that there is an $M$ so that all the members of $\mathbf{q}$ (prime to $M$) are concentrated in a few of the congruence classes $\bmod M?$" If that does not happen, then there is no hope. If it does happen for a certain $M,$ then chances still may be low.

So it very much depends on where $\mathbf{q}$ comes from.

By the way, the problem of finding a $d$ which is a quadratic non-residue relative to all $q \in \mathbf{q},$ is equally difficult.

Comment: Thanks very much, Aaron!  In your example, I'm assuming that you took $p=3$ and $d=7$ just as convenient small numbers?

Comment: In those now deleted lines I  took $p=3$ since it was small and $7$ as  a prime which is $1 \bmod 2p.$ I was probably confused and thinking of this fact: The prime factors of $2^p-1$ are all $1 \bmod 2p.$ So you might be able to get results for certain instances of  "the list of all prime factors of $2^p-1$ where $p$ is a prime congruent to $u \bmod v.$" But, again, only because that restricts congruence classes $\bmod 2d.$

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the update!  I hadn't thought about the properties of generalized Fermat numbers before.  It turns out -1 doesn't quite work for the application I wanted (see edit) but this gives me something I can work with!

Comment: (In particular this shows how to explicitly construct a sequence of integers $d_n$ that work for larger and larger $n$, and that seems like the next best thing.  I'm still wondering if there's a single $d$ that works but I admit now that it seems unlikely!)